# How can I fix the CSV import issue?

Tags: python

I am trying to import this data from a CSV file

```
location    scale
 0.90109    0.63551
0.59587     0.65525
0.80460     0.64227
0.65178     0.65198
0.76307     0.64503
0.52575     0.65915
0.41322 0.66496
0.30059 0.67022
0.21620     0.67382
0.17404 0.67552
-0.05027    0.68363
-0.0782 0.68454
```

Using this code.

```
test=[]
import csv
f=open("data.csv")
for row in csv.reader(f):
    test.append(row)
```

But when I open the test file, I am getting some \xao encodings. Can you tell me how to fix this?

All I want to do is perform some operations on the data after importing into a variable.

[image]

Comment: `.replace(u'\xa0',u'')` first?

Comment: Or `test.append([item.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for item in row])`

Comment: Thanks. But now there is a U infront of every number....

Comment: Is this correct? test.append([item.replace('\xa0', '') for item in row]) It removes the 'u's...

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file appears to contain some [non-breaking space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (0xA0).  Remove those from the file and try again.

Comment: Yeah. The data was made in excel. Please help in remove it programmatically as I don't know how to remove in Excel.